# Refresh tokens are not obtained after Google oAuth

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt

[image]

After giving the authorization code back to google auth to collect the access token and refresh token I am only getting access tokens. I added access_type = offline , prompt = consent and approval_prompt = force but it is still giving me access tokens only?